# Inheriting from a template class in c++ with enum as template parameter

Tags: c++, inheritance, refactoring, c++98

I have some equal classes that contain enum with named constants (like Parts below) and text description for constants (like Parts but strings). Each source class looks like union (not c++ union :-) ) of two classes below. Want to remove code redundancy and got something like this for now:

```
template<class T> class SomeBaseClass
{
public:
    std::string toString()
    {
        uint32_t pairsNum = pairs.size();
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < pairsNum; i++)
            if (pairs[i].first == name) {
                return pairs[i].second;
            }
        // exception will be here
        return std::string("");
    }
    void fromString(std::string name)
    {
        uint32_t pairsNum = pairs.size();
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < pairsNum; i++)
            if (pairs[i].second == name) {
                this->name = pairs[i].first;
                return;
            }
        throw std::invalid_argument(name);
    }
    T get()
    {
        return name;
    }
    void set(T name)
    {
        this->name = name;
    }
private:
    T name;
    std::vector<std::pair<T, std::string> > pairs;
};

class Child: public SomeBaseClass<Child::Parts>
{
public:
    enum Parts { head, rightLeg, leftLeg, rightHand, leftHand, body };
    Child()
    { 
        /* filling SomeBaseClass::pairs by values will be here */
    }
};
```

But Child::Parts is nested type and not a user type for c++98 (can't use more than c++98 standard for this program) so compiler gives error (as expected). I don't want move out Parts from Child because it part of Child ideologically. Is there a beauty way to solve this situation?

Comment: Out of interest, what specifically _is_ the error?

Comment: It looks like rather than inheriting from `SomeBaseClass` `Child` should simply contain a static member `map<Parts, string>`

Comment: To Useless:
There was two errors: 
1) error: incomplete type ‘Child’ used in nested name specifier 
class Child: public SomeBaseClass<Child::Parts>
2) template argument 1 is invalid
class Child: public BaseClass<Child::Parts>

Comment: To Jonathan Mee:
I use Parts type inside of base class. Even if I make map in child this give me nothing because of "T get()" and "void set(T name)". Moreover pairs in this case a common part so it must be in base class imho :) .

Comment: @Jonathan Mee But yes, map is better here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't want move out Parts from Child because it part of Child ideologically

This doesn't mean it has to be stored right inside the `Child` class itself.
What you want to accomplish is impossible like that, C++98 or not. The common approach is to use *traits*:

```
template <typename>
struct Child_traits;

class Child;

template <>
struct Child_traits<Child> {
   enum Parts { head, rightLeg, leftLeg, rightHand, leftHand, body };
};

template <typename T>
class SomeBaseClass {
   typedef typename Child_traits<T>::Parts Parts;

   // use Parts type
};

class Child : public SomeBaseClass<Child> { 
    typedef Child_traits<Child>::Parts Parts; // get the parts type to the child
};
```

The bond between `Child` and `Parts` is established by template specialization (also available in C++98): the `Child` type acts as a key to the right specialization containing the correct `Parts` type.

Comment: I broke my mind with inheritance of template on child (looks like endless loop :-) ) but... it works! :-) Thank you.

Comment: @huan-kun This is called the CRTP.

Comment: Template fully justifies its name. Thanks again.

Comment: @Jodocus what does CRTP stand for?

Comment: @JonathanMee This can be google'd quickly, but anyways, it stands for *curiously recurring template pattern*.